# Check if all the positive values from an array are consecutive

Tags: python

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-consecutive-ones-or-zeros-in-a-binary-array/
Does anyone have an idea how to modify this code so that it returns if all positive values (1) are consecutive?

Basically, I don't want the counter that tells me the maximum number of 1 consecutive, I want to return if absolutely all are consecutive, so in case all are consecutive, the answer would be true, otherwise it would be false.

In the example: arr = **[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]** it would return **false** cause there are 0 between the 1, not all are consecutive BUT in this = arr = **[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]** it would return **true** cause all the 1 are consecutive.

I didn't try anything cause I don't know how to start, maybe with a combination of booleans?. I'm working with python just in case!

Thank you all!

Comment: I could not post my answer. here -> https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/UsJlq4iptE

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a homework question so I won't give you the code but here's some pseudocode.

This is by no means efficient but is quite intuitive

tracker = []
arr = [0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 12, 11, 10]
iterating through every index, keep track of how many times that number has come up

1. if the number has never been seen before

   - set that index to 1 ie. tracker[index] = 1
2. if it has been seen before

   - increment tracker[index] by 1
   - check if 
     arr[index-1] equals arr[index]

     - if it does not, then its not
       consecutive

Comment: This is like homework basically, but don't worry I have string values, not 1 and 0 and I just wanna understand how should I do it and this helped me. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with numpy .  Taking the difference between successive elements will leave you with zeros where neighbors are equal, +1 where the neighbor increases (like 1 to the right of 0) and negative where the neighbor decreases. So the following works, also for numbers other than 0,1:

```
import numpy as np
z=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,3])
all(np.diff(z)>=0)

Out[9]: True

z=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1])
all(np.diff(z)>=0)

Out[11]: False
```

Comment: gives false for `z=np.array([0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,1])`  will work only for binary data

Comment: this one also will give you false --> `np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0])`

Comment: I didn't knew that numpy could do this, that's great! I can't use numpy in this case but thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Pygirl both those examples do and should give False

Comment: but it should give true.

Comment: [0,2,1] is not consecutive, nor is [0,1,0].   "Consecutive numbers are numbers that follow each other in order." from wikipedia